# Upload Images inside Partial View MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap, razor, file-upload

I have a view where the user can edit his profile as follows

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditProfile", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{<div class="container">
     @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ProfileDetails.ProfileError))
        {
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">x</a>     
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.ProfileError).ToString()
            </div>
        }
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well span6 offset0">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.UserName, new { @placeholder = "Username", data_role = "Username", @maxlength = "25" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Firstname</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.Firstname, new { @placeholder = "Firstname", @maxlength = "25" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Surname</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.Surname, new { @placeholder = "Surname", @maxlength = "25" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.EmailAddress, new { @placeholder = "Email Address", @maxlength = "50" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="well span6">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProfileDetails.Gender, Model.ProfileDetails.UsersGender)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.DateOfBirth, new { @placeholder = "Date of Birth", @class = "form_datetime", @maxlength = "10" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Height</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProfileDetails.UsersHeight, Model.ProfileDetails.UsersHeightList)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Current Gym</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProfileDetails.CurrentGym, Model.ProfileDetails.UsersGymList)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="control-group offset0">
            <label class="control-label">About Me</label>
            <div class="controls span8">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.AboutMe, new { @placeholder = "About me, describe your self", @maxlength = "1000" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group offset0">
            <label class="control-label">Interests</label>
            <div class="controls span8">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.ProfileDetails.Interests, new { @placeholder = "Interests, what do you like doing?", @maxlength = "1000" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Profile" class="btn btn-block btn-success" />
</p> 

}
```

Now Ideally what I would like is for the user to upload images of them selves and be displayed like the following http://www.bootsnipp.com/snipps/thumbnails-like-bootsnipp

Now this upload image part maybe used else where on the site so i thought the ideal thing to use would be a partial-view but when I created the partial-view with Html.AjaxBeginForm this gets render on the page, when I press upload button it goes to the relevant controller when it returns it looses all styles/page etc so I get left with just the partial-view on the screen?

In my mind I envision the user can upload an image(s) save to the database and return back to the view without having to rebuild the hole page

I've looked at the following plugin http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ its a good tool and I take my hat of to the person that created it but I'm looking for something more lightweight.

Is the above possible?

Thank.

**Update**
I've plugged the above fileuploader in to my site

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

but when it saves the images and returns back the image i've just uploaded is massive its not longer the thumbnail?

I've check my js files to make sure there in the correct order judging by the demo I downloaded and they match

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>EditProfile</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/canvas-to-blob.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/load-image.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="../../Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.5.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-mygymdate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script src="../../FileUpload/jquery.iframe-transport.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/jquery.fileupload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/jquery.fileupload-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/locale.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FileUpload/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can anyone spot anything that would cause the image to be full sized instead of the thumbnail?

Comment: @Brad, Why can't you use simple ajax calls to upload form and display uploaded images in img tag using JQuery.

Comment: @KarthikBammidi that's exactly what I'm looking for but every time I Google and find possible solutions they all point to the plugin I've mentioned above?

Comment: yes plugin might not give the proper customizations that what exactly we need we need to compromise with that plugin. so if we write our own ajax calls we can have the code satisfaction and also the customization.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link or sample code showing how to do this sort of thing?, bare in mind thought the images they upload get saves to SQL database

Comment: Need to save image as byte array or simple link is enough?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you might find useful [TwitterBootstrapMVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc)